# set -e makes function stop running early?

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I have a function that seems to break when I turn on errors with `set -e`.  I suspect that it is working as intended but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

my_function() {
    base_dir="/tmp/test"
    if [ ! -d $base_dir ]; then
        echo "Creating $base_dir"
        mkdir -p $base_dir
        touch $base_dir/some-file.txt
    fi

    is_edited=$(grep "foo" $base_dir/some-file.txt)

    if [ ! -z $is_edited  ]; then
        cd $base_dir
        echo "Doing stuff"
        docker run --rm debian ls
    fi

    echo
    echo "Done"
    echo
}

my_function
```

With `set -e` flipped on, the function returns seemingly without hit the echo statements.  With `set -e` turned off, the echo statements get hit.  What is happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: `grep` returns a non-zero exit code if it doesn't find a match. This will be treated as an error by `set -e`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, that makes sense.  Maybe there is a better approach to this than using grep or is there a better way to handle the return value for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
is_edited=$(grep "foo" $base_dir/some-file.txt || test $? -eq 1)
```

The exit status of `grep` is `0` if it found a match, `1` if it didn't find a match, and `2` if it got an actual error. So if there's no match for `foo` in the file, it will be considered an error, and `set -e` will terminate the script. The above code translates `1` to a success, so the script will only terminate if `grep` gets a real error.

If you don't care about terminating the script if `grep` gets an error, you could just use

```
if grep -1 "foo" $base_dir/some-file.txt ; then
    ...
fi
```

The `-q` option makes it not print the matching line, just set its exit status based on whether it found a match.

Answer (score 1):

as fmtn07 stated, it's with the return code.

try changing the grep statement from:

`is_edited=$(grep "foo" $base_dir/some-file.txt)`

to:

`is_edited=$(grep "foo" $base_dir/some-file.txt || true)`

Comment: This will prevent the script from aborting if `grep` really gets an error.